# embedded PHP preventing scrolling

Tags: php, html, css

so I am using an HTML template, and have a dynamic table generated by PHP. For whatever reason, when I add the php table in, I can no longer scroll on the page. I am wondering if there is some work around, or there is something I should be looking for in the template CSS to fix this.

Here is my HTML with the embedded PHP:

```
<div class="block-head">
     <h2>Datatable All Features</h2>

</div>
<div class="block-content np">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped sortable">
          <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"/></th>
                 <th width="25%">Name</th>
                 <th width="25%">Gender</th>                                    
             </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
               <?php
                   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                         echo "<tr>";
                         echo "<td>" . $row[username] . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $row[gender] . "</td>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>

          </tbody>
     </table>                                        

</div>
```

Here is my query, which I have above my HTML, for whatever it's worth. I know it's deprecated (just not a top priority right now):

```
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markerfollowing WHERE markerID = '$markerid'"); //query
```

When I remove the php in the table, it scrolls fine. When I put it back, no dice.
Sincere thanks for any help!

Here is my solution:

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>' . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: change the $row[username] to $row['username'] and do the same with the gender. let me know if that helps.

Comment: If you continue to have trouble after making the change suggested above, update your post to show your generated HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an error 500 which you cannot see because of your PHP.ini configuration.
change the $row[username] to $row['username'] and do the same with the gender.

This should do the job:

```
 <?php
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick response. I gave that a shot, but not working.

Comment: Write those 2 lines in the TOP of your PHP file and check for PHP errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`
If you get any errors update your question so we could help you to solve them. it might be because you are using the old mysql functions and its deprecated in PHP 5.5.0+. you should use the mysqli/pdo instead.

Comment: Hey, I posted what made it work, which was just understanding the template requirements. I am new to SO, so I would like to know if there's a way to recommend/give you credit for being helpful without selecting you answer as the right one? If so, I will certainly do it.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Not enough reputation. Maybe I will upvote you some day. Thanks again.